# Office365 saml2.0 generate assertions to log in different apps

Tags: office365, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, azure-ad-graph-api

How to log in to office365 via saml2.0 sso, jump to a different app, such as Outlook, Mail

I try to send saml2.0 assertion to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?redirect_uri=https://www.office.com/launch/word`
But it did not work, so somebody can help?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: How to log in to office365 via saml2.0 sso, jump to a different app, such as Outlook, Mail

**Answer**:
As described by [Enabling single sign-on via Office 365](https://support.robinpowered.com/hc/en-us/articles/217408586-Enabling-single-sign-on-via-Office-365), in order to enable SSO via Office 365, you'll need to have an active O365 account connected for calendars. Once the account is connected, Single Sign-On is enabled by default.

(I) Once you are logged in to one web-based Office365 app (such as Outlook or OneNote) using a web browser through SAML 2.0 SSO, then you can  jump to any other different Office365 sub apps. I have validated the SAML 2.0 SSO for different Office365 apps.

The SSO issue for Office365 sub apps is related to SSO configuration through Office365 ADMIN GUI.

(II) On the other hand, SAML 2.0 SSO is also used to log in to other enterprise applications (such as Google G Suite, Salesforce, Dropbox, Box, etc.) parallel with Office 365. This means that once you are logged in to Office365, you are auto-logged in to other enterprise applications authenticated by the same SAML Identity Provider (such as ADFS, Shibboleth IdP, etc.) using the same web browser.  I have also validated the SAML 2.0 SSO for different enterprise apps parallel to Office 365.

The SSO issue for parallel enterprise apps (such as Google G Suite)is related to SSO configuration through SAML Identity Provider's ADMIN GUI.

(III) [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provides the instruction on building your own IDP for SAML in Java using Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP.

- Shibboleth SAML IdP is responsible for identity federation.
- OpenLDAP is responsible for identity authentication.

(IV) I have validated SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) provided by Docker-running Shibboleth SAML IdP (Identity Provider) and OpenLDAP for the following enterprise applications. In other words, I leveraged Docker-running Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP to log in to the following enterprise applications successfully.

```
Microsoft Office 365
Google G Suite
Salesforce
Dropbox
Box
Amazon AWS
OpenStack
Citrix NetScaler
VMware vCloud Director
Oracle NetSuite
```

(V) For your convenience, I have made the 10th commit to upload the Office 365 SP metadata and corresponding SAML configuration to [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP).
**Note that** I have logged in to Office 365 organization "example.com" account (https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=example.com) with username "winston.hong@example.com" successfully using [Shibboleth IdP running with Docker Container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP).

By performing the following Shibboleth SAML IdP configuration procedure, you can log in to your Office 365 organization "your-company.com" account (https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=your-company.com) with your username (such as "winston.hong@your-company.com"). Then you can jump to a different app, such as Outlook, OneDrive, SharePoint, etc

(V.a) Download the source code of building and running Shibboleth SAML IdP from GitHub repository.

```
$git clone https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP
```

(V.b) Edit "LDAP-Dockerized-CentOS/users.ldif" to replace user info "winston.hong@example.com" with your UserId/username "winston.hong@your-company.com" and employeeNumber "xWr5MnS5wEO3siztf9oFuA==" with your Azure AD ImmutableID.

(V.c) Follow the instruction provided by README (https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP/blob/master/README.md) to build and run Shibboleth IdP, OpenLDAP and Shibboleth SP.

Validate that you can log in to Shibboleth SP application through Shibboleth IdP.

(V.d) Use the [public certificate template "shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/credentials/idp-signing.crt" and the 2nd signing certificate of "shibboleth-idp-dockerized/ext-conf/metadata/idp-metadata.xml" to create the assertion signing public certificate of Shibboleth IdP. Then you need to upload the signing certificate of Shibboleth IdP to your Office 365 organization account.

(V.e) Follow the instruction [How to use Shibboleth Identity Provider v3 with Office 365](https://wiki.sunet.se/display/SWAMID/How+to+use+Shibboleth+Identity+Provider+v3+with+Office+365) to complete SAML SP configuration for your Office 365 organization account.

(V.f) Now you can log in to your Office 365 organization account as SAML SP through Shibboleth SAML IdP.

**Remarks**:
(1) Access your organization realm, e.g., outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=example.com

(2) You are redirected to SAML IdP (such as ADFS, Shibboleth IdP)

(3) Authenticated by data repository (such as OpenLDAP or AD or MySQL) provided by SAML IdP

(4) SAML IdP posts SAML2.0 assertion to login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf.

(5) You are logged in to Office265 Email by default, then you can access any Office365 sub app.

The issue of accessing Office365 sub app is caused by Office365, NOT SAML IdP.

Microsoft provides authentication tutorial on Microsoft identity platform - [Handle user consent during token request time and facilitate the dynamic provisioning of apps across tenants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios):

- Enables users and administrators to dynamically grant or deny consent for the app to access resources on their behalf.
- Enables administrators to ultimately decide what apps are allowed to do and which users can use specific apps, and how the directory resources are accessed.

Microsoft provides instruction on [Setting up single sign-on for Office 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2966531/support-options-for-setting-up-single-sign-on-for-office-365)

**Question 2**: I try to send saml2.0 assertion to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?redirect_uri=https://www.office.com/launch/word But it did not work, so somebody can help?

**Answer**:
The  Microsoft official website [Configure SAML 2.0 provider settings for portals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/portals/configure-saml2-settings) demonstrates the HTTP request for decoding SAML Response/Assertion is sent to Office365 SAML SP/Relying Party endpoint (or SAML Assertion Consume Endpoint) using HTTP **POST** instead of HTTP **REDIRECT/GET**

- For ADFS IdP, "Endpoint type: SAML Assertion Consume Endpoints" and "Binding: POST"
- For Shibboleth Identity Provider 3,

```
<AssertionConsumerService index=1 isDefault=true

Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"

Location=https://portal.contoso.com/signin-saml2/>
```

The potential root cause of your error "But it did not work" is that you use **REDIRECT/GET** to send SAML 2.0 assertion to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`

**Resolution**:
You can use **POST** to send SAML 2.0 assertion to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`.

I have validated successful SAML 2.0 SSO for Office365 apps using three (3) different SAML IdPs (i.e., ADFS IdP, Shibboleth IdP, and our own Scala-based SAML IdP).

All three (3) different SAML IdPs use **POST** to send saml2.0 assertion to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`.

We developed our former version of [Zero-Password Authentication and Authorization System](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Zero-Password-Authentication-and-Authorization-System) in **Java** and leveraged Shibboleth IdP to provide SAML SSO for enterprise applications (such as Office365).

We developed our current version of [Zero-Password Authentication and Authorization System](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Zero-Password-Authentication-and-Authorization-System) with scalability and high availability in **Scala** to provide SAML SSO natively for enterprise applications (such as Office365) without Shibboleth IdP.

Comment: I used HTTP POST to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf and set  RelayState: https://outlook.office365.com or https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1%2E0&rver=6%2E1%2E6206%2E0&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Foffice.live.com%2Fstart%2FWord.aspx%3Fauth%3D2&whr=mydomain. But it also did not work, I mean jump to sub app after sso login success

Comment: The SSO issue for Office365 sub apps is related to SSO configuration through Office365 ADMIN GUI. (1) RelayState is a random string. (2) Your Office 365 login URL should be outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=example.com (example is your organization domain assigned by Microsoft). I have updated my answer to provide more details.

Comment: you mean post saml2.0 assertion to https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=example.com  ?

Comment: No. (1) Access outlook.office365.com/owa/?realm=example.com, (2) Redirected to SAML IdP, (3) Authenticated by data repository provided by SAML IdP. (4) SAML IdP post SAML2.0 assertion to login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf. (5) Logged in to Office265 Email by default, then you can access any Office365 sub app. The sub app issue is caused by Office365, NOT SAML IdP, see Handle user consent and facilitate the dynamic provisioning of apps across tenants. I share Shibboleth IdP for Office 365. I have updated my answer again.